# How to have both lm and fixest model with different vcov standard errors in modelsummary package?

Tags: r, modelsummary, fixest

I'd like to create an LM with HC3 corrected standard errors and a fixest model with cluster robust standard errors in the same table.

see my MRE below:

```
df <- mtcars

models <- list()
models[[1]] <- lm(cyl~disp, data = df)
models[[2]] <- feols(cyl~disp|as.factor(gear), data = df)
library(modelsummary)

# this works
modelsummary::modelsummary(models)

# but these do not
modelsummary::modelsummary(models, vcov = c("HC3", "cluster"))
modelsummary::modelsummary(models, vcov = c(HC3, cluster))
modelsummary::modelsummary(models, vcov = list(HC3, cluster))
modelsummary::modelsummary(models, vcov = list(vcovHC, cluster))
modelsummary::modelsummary(models, vcov = list(vcovHC, vcovHC))
modelsummary::modelsummary(models, vcov = c(vcovHC, vcovHC))
```

Okay--I figured out a hack, but still leaving question open in case someone finds out a more slick solution.

```
df <- mtcars
models <- list()
fit <- lm(cyl~disp, data = df)
models[[1]] <- coeftest(fit, vcovHC(fit, type = "HC3"))
models[[2]] <- summary(feols(cyl~disp|as.factor(gear), data = df), "cluster")
library(modelsummary)

# this works
modelsummary::modelsummary(models)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `fixest` automatically computes cluster-robust standard errors when you include fixed effects. If you set `vcov=NULL`, `modelsummary` will return the default standard errors, which will then be cluster-robust.

Alternatively, you can set `vcov=~gear` to compute the standard errors using the `sandwich::vcovCL` function under the hood.

Using version 0.10.0 of `modelsummary` and 0.10.4 of `fixest`, we can do:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(fixest)

models <- list(
    lm(cyl~disp, data = mtcars),
    feols(cyl ~ disp | gear, data = mtcars),
    feols(cyl ~ disp | gear, data = mtcars))

modelsummary(models,
             fmt = 6,
             vcov = list("HC3", NULL, ~gear))
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 3.188568 |  |  |
|  | (0.289130) |  |  |
| disp | 0.012998 | 0.012061 | 0.012061 |
|  | (0.001310) | (0.002803) | (0.002803) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 | 32 |
| R2 | 0.814 | 0.819 | 0.819 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.807 | 0.800 | 0.800 |
| R2 Within |  | 0.614 | 0.614 |
| R2 Pseudo |  |  |  |
| AIC | 79.1 | 80.2 | 80.2 |
| BIC | 83.5 | 86.1 | 86.1 |
| Log.Lik. | -36.573 | -36.107 | -36.107 |
| F | 98.503 |  |  |
| Std.Errors | HC3 | by: gear | by: gear |
| FE: gear |  | X | X |

Notice that the results are the same in the 2nd and 3rd column, and also equal to the plain `fixest` summary:

```r
summary(models[[2]])
#> OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: cyl
#> Observations: 32 
#> Fixed-effects: gear: 3
#> Standard-errors: Clustered (gear) 
#>      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> disp 0.012061   0.002803 4.30299 0.049993 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> RMSE: 0.747808     Adj. R2: 0.799623
#>                  Within R2: 0.614334
```

In some past versions of `modelsummary` there were issues with *labelling* of the standard errors at the bottom of the table. I will soon be working on a more robust system to make sure the label matches the standard errors. In most cases, `modelsummary` calculates the robust standard errors itself, so it has full control over labelling and computation. Packages like `fixest` and `estimatr` make things a bit more tricky because they sometimes hold several SEs, and because the default is not always “classical”.